# "Function" is function, how is that possible?

Tags: javascript, object

In js we have a function named "*Function*".
An instance of it returns a function:

```
var myfunc = new Function('arg1','arg2','return arg1+arg2');
```

In that example the variable *myfunc* contains a function that returns the sum of two given params.

My question is - how is that possible that *Function* is a function? It can't be an instance of itself.
And *Object* is a function too, an instance of *Function*. But *Function* is an instance of *Object* because function are objects.

And I can't understand how is it possible, it's an infinity loop...

Thanks.

Comment: You're calling Function's constructor. I would maybe do some research on the use of the `new` keyword.

Comment: There comes a certain point when things stop being implemented in JavaScript and are implemented in the runtime.  This is one of those seams, I would imagine :).

Comment: @Corbin: That's not really related to it. `Function.toString()
 === "function Function() {\n    [native code]\n}"`, i.e. it *is* a function.

Comment: I'd better ask *why is `Function` object needed in JS?*...

Comment: @ThiefMaster If I understand his question correctly, he's essentially wondering how Function is implemented.  While my comment does not exactly answer that, I believe at the end of his string of digging will be native code.  Seems I've misunderstood the question though :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trivial answer is "because ECMA-262 says so".

Objects like [Function](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3), Object, Array, Date etc. are built–in objects so they aren't constructed in the usualy way, they just are. The relationship between them, their prototype and their `[[Prototype]]` is established by the environment in accordance with ECMA-262. So Function [inherits from its own prototype](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.3) (i.e. `Function.prototype === Function[[Prototype]]`), which inherits from Object.prototype.

Answer (score 2):

`Object`, `Function`, etc. are indeed functions - constructor functions to be exact.

Remember, you create an object like this:

```
function MyObject() {
    this.foo = 'bar';
}

var my = new MyObject();
alert(my.foo);
```

---

By the way, using `new Function(...)` is usually a bad idea. Your example would be much cleaner like this:

```
function myfunc(arg1, arg2) { return arg1 + arg2 }
```

or

```
var myfunc = function(arg1, arg2) { return arg1 + arg2 };
```

So there are few reasons to use `new Function()` in production (template engines are a good usecase for it though).

Comment: It was an example and I don't do that but I want to know how does it work.

Comment: But again - how _Function_ is an instance of itself?

Comment: @iiddaannyy: It isn't an *instance* in the sense that the `Function` constructor was invoked to create the `Function` constructor. Clearly that's not possible. The `Function` constructor is created by the underlying implementation, and is given the necessary properties so that  `instanceof` interprets it as being an instance of `"Function"`.

Comment: ...you can read about it in the spec here: http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.3 ...and I shouldn't have `"Function"` in quotes in the last word of my previous comment. It should read: *...interprets it as being an instance of `Function`.*